# Paired test taking into account single observation errors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two sets of paired observations that I would like to see if they are statistically different. However, each individual observation has an associated uncertainty (SD). For most common paired tests that I have seen the error of each individual data point is not taken into account.

Do you know the best way to proceed with the analysis of such datasets represents paired observation where each observation has a error associated with?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am strong proponent of proof by bootstrap

Not rigorous methodology (I haven't heard of one), but if you make some assumptions on the differences (e.g. normality), you can maybe calculate a new array representing pairs (mean difference, variance) and then use bootstrap to arrive at an answer like this:

for i $\in$ B samples

do N times and store in $vector_i$, where N is the size of your original data set, with replacement

1. Sample random index
2. Sample from difference distribution N(mean difference_i, variance) of that index

calculate the means of each $vector_i$

Then, you are left with B mean samples that should be roughly from the same distribution than your original sample, thus you can look at how many mean samples are above 0, for example (if it's 99.5%, you might conclude that the means aren't equal)